# How to replace a function of an executable C++ program by a shared library?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries, executable

I would like to implement a shared library (`change_func1`) which replaces a function (`func1()`) in the !!! EXECUTABLE !!!, such that another text (e.g. "Hello Universe!") is printed out instead of "Hello World!".

Here is my source code so far:

**change_func1.hpp**

```
#ifndef _CHANGE_FUNC1_HPP
#define _CHANGE_FUNC1_HPP

#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace change_func1
{
    void func1(void);

    void hijack_func1(void);
}

#endif /* _CHANGE_FUNC1_HPP */
```

**change_func1.cpp**

```
#include "change_func1.hpp"

namespace change_func1
{
    void func1(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello Universe!" << std::endl;
    }

    void hijack_func1(void)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "change_func1.hpp"

void func1(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    change_func1::hijack_func1();

    func1();

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the instructions for the g++ compiler:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -shared -fPIC change_func1.cpp -o change_func1.so -ldl
g++ -Wall -Wextra -c main.cpp
g++ -o main main.o change_func1.so -ldl
```

With the following command, the function `func1()` in the main executable is replaced by another function which prints out "Hello Universe!"

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/change_func1.so ./main
Hello Universe!
```

What is the best and easiest way to replace a function in an executable by another function with a shared library such that another text is printed out?

My machine has Linux x86.

I hope that someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: Can you explain what `hijack_func1()` is used for here in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately symbols defined in main executable prevail over all others definitions (including definitions coming from `LD_PRELOAD`). So you will *not* be able to intercept function in executable via `LD_PRELOAD`.